# OrientDB - Multiple records showing after re-applying edges

Tags: orientdb

I have a problem. When I create edges first time, the number of records in the output are OK. But, when I add another record to the class and create the edge again, I get multiple records. Here is what I am doing.

```
create class Country extends V
create class Immigrant extends V
create class comesFrom extends E

create property Country.c_id integer
create property Country.c_name String
create property Immigrant.i_id integer
create property Immigrant.i_name String
create property Immigrant.i_country Integer

insert into Country(c_id, c_name) values (1, 'USA')
insert into Country(c_id, c_name) values (2, 'UK')
insert into Country(c_id, c_name) values (3,'PAK')

insert into Immigrant(i_id, i_name,i_country) values (1, 'John',1)
insert into Immigrant(i_id, i_name,i_country) values (2, 'Graham',2)
insert into Immigrant(i_id, i_name,i_country) values (3, 'Ali',3)

create edge comesFrom from (select from Immigrant where i_country = 1) to (select from Country where c_id = 1)
create edge comesFrom from (select from Immigrant where i_country = 2) to (select from Country where c_id = 2)
create edge comesFrom from (select from Immigrant where i_country = 3) to (select from Country where c_id = 3)

select i_id, i_name, out('comesFrom').c_id as c_id, out('comesFrom').c_name as c_name from Immigrant unwind c_id, c_name
```

I get the result as below.

[Click here to view image of correct records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLVE7.png)

Then I add another record to the class Immigrant.

```
insert into Immigrant(i_id, i_name,i_country) values (4, ‘James',2)
```

And create the edge again. Please note that the new immigrant belongs to an already existing country.

```
create edge comesFrom from (select from Immigrant where i_country = 2) to (select from Country where c_id = 2)
```

I run the same query as below.

```
select i_id, i_name, out('comesFrom').c_id as c_id, out('comesFrom').c_name as c_name from Immigrant unwind c_id, c_name
```

Now I get multiple records as below.

[Click here to view image of incorrect records.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NR24P.png)

What wrong am I doing.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this command:

```
create edge comesFrom from (select from Immigrant where i_country = 2) 
to (select from Country where c_id = 2)
```

Because if you execute only this part:

```
select from Immigrant where i_country = 2
```

You can see that there are 2 results: Graham and James.
So, it will create an edge between the two Immigrants (Graham and James) and the Country.
To avoid this problem you can create the edge using the name of the Immigrants.
However I add a couple of attachments so you can understand better.

The problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NptOt.png

Your Solution: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfU6c.png

My Solution: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEEal.png

Regards

Comment: making relations like this becomes too difficult because first I will have to fetch the country id for every immigrant and then link in the suggested way. Excuse me if I my question is too basic, but is there not a way to link a field to a field instead of linking a record to a record? Or do you have any better suggestion?

Comment: I don't think you can do it, but Ifound this chapter in the documentation if you want look it, but in my opinion it doesn't worth it,I prefer use edges beacuse it's more easy.